# Possivel redirecionar função sem rota no Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Estou utilizando uma funcionalidade para gerar relatorios em PDF utilizando Laravel. Porém estou em duvida se é possivel a partir de um simples botão de HTML, poder redirecionar automaticamente para uma função do meu **controller** sem ter que criar uma nova rota. Eu gostaria como exemplo colocar a função e transformar em um objeto para assim ser chamada na view como mostrado abaixo.

```
<a href="{{generatePDF()}}" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Gerar PDF</a>
```

**Como aconteceria no JavaScript**. A função que desejo redirecionar é essa:

```
function generatePDF(){
            $pdf = PDF::loadView('dashboard-pdf',$dados)->setPaper('a4', 'landscape');
            return $pdf->stream();
        }
```

Seria possivel fazer algo parecido com o Laravel ou teria mesmo que criar uma nova rota só para realizar essa função?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que pode ser feito é você criar uma pasta de Helpers no seu app, criar um arquivo com sua função e carrega-la através do composer, inserindo em composer.json, em "autoload" (conforme exemplo):

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Intranet\\": "app/"
    },
    "classmap": [
        "database/seeds",
        "database/factories"
    ],
    "files": [
        "app/Helpers/ArquivoComFuncoes.php"
    ]
```

Dessa forma sua função ficará disponível para toda a aplicação.

Entretanto, não vejo motivos para não fazer uso das rotas (o que está dentro das boas práticas).

Comment: É que eu possuo um código grande para adicionar os valores corretos em $dados. E daí pensei em alguma forma de reduzir um pouco essa quantidade de código. Mas se fazer isso equivale a praticas ruins. Pretenderei criar rotas normais mesmo.